# I have an error when I genobject ORDS using Oracle SQLcl

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-ords, sqlcl, oracle-rest-data-services

I have following error when I want to export ORDS object using:

```
SQL> lb genobject -type ORDS;
ORA-20850: Parameter p_module_id must not be null.
ORA-06512: at "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_EXPORT", line 235
ORA-06512: at "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_EXPORT", line 645
ORA-06512: at "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_EXPORT", line 645
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Even if I use name of REST module:

```
SQL> lb genobject -type ORDS -name siga;

Processing has failed for your request.
ORA-20850: Parameter p_module_id must not be null.
ORA-06512: at "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_EXPORT", line 235
ORA-06512: at "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_EXPORT", line 534
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I use following versions:

- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
- Production ORDS: 19.2.0.r1991647 SQLcl Oracle SQLDeveloper
- Command-Line (SQLcl) version: 21.3.3.0 build: 21.3.3.322.1724

Thank you

Comment: Your ords might be too old...the sqlcl liquibase feature came AFTER July 2019...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in ORDS versions 18.2 to 19.2. You will need to upgrade to ORDS 19.3 or later to resolve the issues.

Oracle Support Bug Link: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2670281.1

Comment: Thank you! That fix my problem